# Pin detection using blobs

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Detect pin heads using blobs

I am developing an application which detects PCB pins and their bending. I have the following images:
[Pins Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g3JG.png)
[Pins Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImDGa.png)

As you can see in the images the top of the pins are shiny, some pins are more shiny, some are less shiny. I have done the following operations on the images:

1. Convert the images to grayscale
2. Apply Gaussian Blur
3. Apply thresholding
4. Dilation
5. Closing
6. Opening

After these operations I use the `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector` functions to detect the blobs.

However, I can't find a set of operations and parameters for these operations to get good blobs, that would fit both cases.

If I apply a threshold that is too big so I can detect correctly the pins in the second image, I can't detect the blobs in the first image since the pins are less shiny.
[Second Image Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQM07.png)
[First Image Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUOVq.png)

If the binarization threshold is too low, I get artifacts in the second image which will affect the blob detection algorithm.

[Second Image Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14O4X.png)
[First Image Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwZ2l.png)

Is there any way I can get the 2 pin heads in both cases using OpenCV?

Comment: I can't tell what I'm seeing in those first two pictures. they're blurry, strange perspective.